# Toolbar duplicado - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo el siguiente `toolbar` en mi aplicación de android que estoy desarrollando:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tbLoguinActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:title="@string/action_sign_in"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_icon" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtAbTitulo"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtAbSubTitulo"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/IniciarSesion" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hace lo que deseo, por eso no tengo problema, pero hay un string que esta colocando el nombre de la App, con el XML que tengo, según yo debería mostrarme algo así:
[image: resultado esperado]

pero por alguna razón, al correrlo en mi dispositivo móvil (Samsung galaxy grand prime: Android 5.0.2 API 21) me muestra de esta manera la aplicación:
[image: resultado actual]

**NominaBSI** es el nombre de mi aplicación, el que sale junto al subtítulo es el que yo pongo en mi XML, pero el que sale al lado izquierdo del ícono no me explico la razón de que aparezca ahí.
Cabe aclarar que el código de la aplicación está en blanco, sólo asigné el toolbar a la activity, de todas formas, dejo el código de mi app:

**EDIT: he intentado utilizar la propiedad setTitle, con el mismo resultado**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_loguin);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tbLoguinActivity);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
}
```

*Removí la etiqueta `android:label` de mi archivo manifest, y sigue con el mismo resultado.*

```
<activity android:name=".ActLoguin">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**¿cómo remuevo ese título?**

Comment: Puedes oclutar el Toolbar programaticamente: `if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }`, elimina estas dos lineas de código `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas cargando el tuyo propio y el de android, puedes eliminarlo de una de estas dos maneras:

Agregando en el codigo:

```
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

O en el AndroidManifest.xml puedes buscar la etiqueta application y dejar vacía la linea

```
android:label=""
```

Recomiendo la primera opcion, ya que la segunda podria ocasionar algun problema si llegas a usar intent-filter o alguna otra cosa que lo perjudique.

EDITO: Elimina de tu código la linea:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: He editado la respuesta con una nueva propuesta

Comment: eso me funcionó muchas gracias :) lo puse por seguir [este tutorial](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/actionbar-appbar-toolbar-en-android-ii/). ¿qué fue lo que acabo de eliminar? jajaja

Comment: Lo que hace es colocar la toolbar como barra de acción. Puedes crear una toolbar personalizada como has realizado, pero Android trae herramientas para realizarla poniendo icono, titulo, subtitulo... básicamente lo que has realizado es posible sin crear una personalizada. Entonces al usar la tuya propia, no hay que llamar a dicho metodo para que no aparezca la tuya y la de android. Todo esto depende del Style que tengas definido, si tienes o no un titulo puesto...